# Alternative for Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named gs that has information about various symbols, such as Arizona's flag, Arizona's state flower, etc., where Arizona is represented by the value (IDArea) us-az.

A second table - gw_geog - has more information about places, including the full names (e.g. Arizona) and parents (e.g. usa).

A third table - gs2_latin - simply standardizes Latin names. For example, two states may have different names for the same flower (stored in table gs), but both flowers have the same Latin name (stored in gs2_latin).

I have a query that displays a table listing all 50 states alphabetically, along with their state symbols (state birds, in this case), like this...

Alabama | yellowhammer

Alaska | ptarmigan

Nebraska | western meadowlark

Wyoming | western meadowlark

Now I want to write a second query that groups all the places together, so my second table displays like this:

yellowhammer | Alabama

ptarmigan | Alaska

western meadowlark | Nebraska, Wyoming

I haven't yet figured out exactly what the query will look like, and I'm not even sure if I need to include the table gs2_latin. But I hit a problem with my first experiment that has me puzzled.

In my original table, the following dictates that GName will display the name of a state or country...

```
$Place = $row['GName'];
```

Since I now want to display EVERY state or country associated with a particular symbol, I changed it to this:

```
$Place[] = $row['GName'];
```

But I get the following error:

Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

My query's not finished and may be a little sloppy. But can you see any obvious reasons for this error message? Or is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do? Thx.

P.S. The most important values in the query below are GS.Symbol (the name of a particular symbol; e.g. sunflower), GS.Latin (a symbol's scientific name) and GName (the name of a state or country).

```
SELECT GG.N, GG.IDArea, GG.URL GURL, GG.Name GName, GG.Type, GG.IDParent, GG.Parent, GG.ParentName, GG.IDReg,
GS.N, GS.IDArea SymArea, GS.URL, GS.IDSymbol, GS.Title, GS.PageKind3, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin,
GS.Desig, GS.DesigGen, GS.DesigGroup, G4.Common, G4.Latin
FROM gw_geog AS GG
LEFT JOIN gs AS GS ON GS.IDArea = GG.IDArea
LEFT JOIN gs2_latin AS G4 ON G4.Common = GS.Symbol
WHERE GG.IDParent = 'usa' AND GS.DesigGen = :RefCat
GROUP BY GS.IDSymbol ORDER BY GS.N
```

Comment: If you want to use `$Place[] = $row['GName'];` then `$Place` must be an array

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory... `$Place` is a string before your `$Place[] = ...` line, when it should be an array, like Mark said. Step backwards from that line and find where you're setting it to a string value.

Comment: `$Place` is a variable that already exists, and is a string. If you initialize the variable with `$Place = array();` there is no problem (but probably you should either name this one differently then your already existing variable, or perhaps you have set it to string somewhere accidentally).

Comment: You can use MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to create a pipe separated string: `GROUP_CONCAT(' | ', GName)`

Comment: @ Wrikken - I think your suggestion is the solution. I renamed Place to PlaceGroup, and I no longer get that error message. Unfortunately, I now have another problem to fix. In the first row, $PlaceGroup correctly displays Alabama. In the Alaska row, instead of displaying Alaska, it displays AlabamaAlaska. Things keep piling up until the last row lists all 50 states. But I might be able to fix that by simply playing around with the code.